# Vim in terminal is black-&-white but vim launched from dash shows colors

Tags: syntax-highlighting, colorscheme, terminal

I am using Vim 7 on Ubuntu 16.04 (gnome) and the terminal emulator I am using is terminator.

I really like the aristocrat/brogrammer colorscheme for Python and so I copy-pasted it in `~/.vim/colors/brogrammer.vim`.

Now here's my problem: when I run vim inside terminal and then set colorscheme to brogrammer then I get ugly black & white look, like so

[image: ugly]

on the contrary, if I press `super`, type `vim` (i.e. if I launch it as a program from dash and not by typing `vim` in terminal) and then set colorscheme to brogrammer I get beautiful colors, like so

[image: nice]

---

Why is this happening? what can I do to show those beautiful colors even when launched from terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon closer inspection I found that the vim instance showing correct colors was in fact being run on gnome-terminal, as seen by `ps aux | grep -i term`.

Evidently, the problem can be sorted by explicitly setting `t_Co` to 256 in the color scheme's `.vim` file so as to ensure consistent behavior across all terminal emulators supporting 256+ colors.

So,

***why is this happening***: different terminal emulators default to different color bit ranges.

***what can I do...***: Two possible solutions:

1. In your .bashrc or .zshrc or whatever, set `TERM` such that it ends with `-256color`, something like `set TERM=xterm-256color` (thanks to [this](https://answers.launchpad.net/terminator/+question/212170) and @Rich)
2. Or, if you don't what to mess with terminal's settings; open the desired color scheme's .vim file and add the line `set t_Co=256` near the top

Comment: If OP uses Vim 8+ or NeoVim 0.2+ then should use `set termguicolors` instead (if terminal supports that).

Comment: If `t_Co` isn't already set to 256, then that means your terminal is configured incorrectly. Overriding it in Vim is a workaround, but a better solution is to fix your terminal configuration. What's the output of `tput colors` when run in your terminal?

Comment: I was having the same issue on Google Cloud Shell